# How do you replicate a modal cross dissolve animation?

Tags: iphone, ios, modal-dialog, segue

I have a game that has a replay button at the top of it. If you press the replay button the level restarts. Well, to accomplish this I used to do a segue from the button to its own vc, but i have been told thats bad because your just adding vc's to the stack when you dont have to.

So, i decided to just reset all the attributes, but I also want the cool cross disolve animation that you get when doing a modal segue. How can i add this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try with animations in layer, for example:

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 2.0;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionFade;
transition.delegate = self;
[self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
self.view.hidden = YES;
self.view.hidden = NO;
```

this way every change you do in view will animate the view...

Comment: after i imported <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

Comment: and tried running i got this error

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CATransition", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CAMediaTimingFunction", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
  "_kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut", referenced from:
      -[ViewController replayButton:] in ViewController.o
  "_kCATransitionFade", referenced from:
      -[ViewController rld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

Comment: clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)eplayButton:] in ViewController.o

Comment: huumm, i've tested it in 4.3 and 5.1 just to make sure it works and all i needed is quartz core imported...
have you added the quartzcore librarie to the project?

Comment: o, cool its working now, its just that it doesnt quite look like a modal cross dissolve transition.